# Rails Haml ending an If statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I need to automate the following:

box 
Category 1 
   bunch of tables

box 
Category 2 
   bunch of tables

... etc

I can do this if I can end the if statement that prints the header but I can't because of the indentation, If I move the table part to the if statement level, the tables don't go inside the boxes

```
- @test = -1
- @c.each do |p|
  - if p.category_id != @test
    = @test = p.category_id
    .box
      boxname
      .box-content.padded{:style => "..."}

    %table.table-condensed{:align => "left"}
      %tr
        %td{:align => "center", :style => "..."}
        = p.name
      %tr
        %td{:align => "center"}
        %div{:id => pod....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do things like this in Haml, you should get your data in the right format first, and then the markup should follow simply.

In this case (if I’ve understood you correctly) it looks like you could use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to group each category together. Something like this (simplified from your code):

```
- @c.group_by(&:category_id).each do |category, values|
  = category
  .box
    ...
    %table
      - values.each do |p|
        %tr
          %td
            = p.name
```